# Azure Active Directory App won't work as expected with policy not default 'true' to org

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

My Azure App: **Public client type** - see screenshot from Azure Portal:
[image]

My policy:

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy": 
 {"Version":1,
"MaxAgeSingleFactor":"00:12:00",  
"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:10:00",  
"MaxInactiveTime":"00.00:10:00", 
"MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"00:12:00", 
"MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor":"00:12:00",
"MaxAgeMultiFactor":"00:12:00"}}') -DisplayName "t2" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

When I attempt with `device code flow` and read a file from Data Lake Gen 2 - the above works - i.e. I can see that the `expiresOn` is after `10` minutes and when I try to read after `12` minutes i get that maxtime has been exceeded.

However when I recreate the above policy:
 1. With `-IsOrganizationDefault $true`
 2. Then attach the policy to my app with:  `Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id $app.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id`

Then attempt `device code flow` I know it does not work because the `expiresOn` is after 1 hour which is the default value...

Would anyone know why it works **only** when is org default value is set to `true`? but not when is set to `false` **and** attached to my public app??

Comment: Anything else is unclear about my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy` cmdlet is not available at this time.

It's included in the preview version. So this cmdlet may still be in the process of improvement.

See details from the first sentence [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadapplicationpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview&viewFallbackFrom=azureadps-2.0).